# refreshing webview in android

Tags: android, webview, meta

I have standard webview in my android code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}
```

i dont have any code in there about reloading/refeshing.
but i have this code below in the page that the webview is bringing up.

```
<META http-equiv="REFRESH" content="30">
```

I know very old school, but it does the job I need for now.

But, webview isn't respecting that meta tag exactly, it has nothing to with webkit because i've tried lots of browsers with success.

webview refeshes the app it seems when it wants to, not every 30 secs as instructed.

how can I get webview to refresh every 30 secs or faster, with no issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CountDownTimer to reload the URL again and again after 30 seconds

```
new CountDownTimer(365 * 24 * 60 * 60, 30000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
   ACTIVITY_NAME.this.mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
 }

 public void onFinish() {
    //Done 
 }
}.start();
```